# Unable to resolve DNS for server after setting up a domain using Cloud DNS

Tags: google-cloud-dns

I followed the steps in the tutorial:
https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/tutorials/create-domain-tutorial

However when I get to the verify my setup, I don't see my servers IP, instead I see this:

```
$ dig -t NS dandyrobot.com.

; <<>> DiG 9.18.1-1ubuntu1.2-Ubuntu <<>> -t NS dandyrobot.com.
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 56042
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dandyrobot.com.            IN  NS

;; Query time: 2339 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue Feb 07 11:00:42 EST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 43
```

Are there any additional steps I can take to narrow down what the problem is?

Comment: Did you register your domain under Google Domains?

Comment: Yes, and added the custom name servers there as well

Comment: The information you shared shows that your domain is dandyrobot.com right? Can you type the external IP address of your website to the address bar to check if it is working. Also consider the [propagation](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/update-name-servers#:~:text=can%20take%20from-,48%20to%2072%20hours,-to%20propagate.) that may take 48 to 72 hours

Comment: Yeah thats correct. I can confirm it is working using the external IP. I went through the tutorial on Friday, so should be long past the 72 hours

Comment: Can you share the NS server from your Cloud DNS?

Comment: ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-d3.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-d4.googledomains.com

Comment: I tried to dig the domain and it is showing a different name server NS-CLOUD-A1.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
NS-CLOUD-A2.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
NS-CLOUD-A3.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
NS-CLOUD-A4.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
can you double check the configuration of your google domain and make sure that custom name server is in use. You can use this [link](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3290309?hl=en) for guidance.

Comment: Ah you are right, I was looking at the wrong google domain page. Should be correct now, but will give it more time to fully propagate before verifying

Comment: Nice, that is great to hear. Please keep us users posted on this concern. Once the changes are already propagated Ill post our solution as an answer to guide other users with the same concern.

Comment: Based on a `nslookup` command, it looks like its getting the right IP address!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our conversation what seems to be the problem is that the configuration of custom nameserver under Google Domains. Then we use this [link](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3290309?hl=en) as a guidance to resolve this concern.